# ElasticSearch - what is the difference between an index template and an index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have read an explanation to my question here:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/whats-the-differece-between-index-pattern-and-index-template/54948

However, I still don't understand the difference. When defining an index PATTERN, does it not affect index creation at all? Also, what happens if I create an index but it doesn't have a corresponding index pattern? How can I see the mapping used for an index pattern so I can know how to use the Mapping API to update it?

And on a side note, the docs say you manage the index patterns by clicking the "Settings" and then "Indices" tab. I'm looking at Kibana and I don't see any settings tab. I can view the index patterns through the management tab, but I don't see any settings tab there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) is an ES feature for triggering the creation of new indexes whenever a name pattern is matched. For instance, let's say we create the following index template:

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["foo*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, as soon as we want to index a document inside an index named (e.g.) `foo-44` and that index doesn't exist, then that template (settings + mappings) will be used by ES in order to create the `foo-44` index automatically.

You can update an index template at any time by simply PUTting a new settings/mappings definition like above.

An [index pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html) (not to be confounded with the `index-patterns` property you saw above, those are two totally different things), is a Kibana feature for telling Kibana what makes up an index (all the fields, their types, etc). Nothing can happen in Kibana without creating index patterns, which you can do in `Management > Index Patterns`.

Creating an index in ES will not create any index pattern in Kibana. Similarly, creating an index pattern in Kibana will not create any index in ES.

The reason why Kibana needs an index pattern is because it needs to store different kind of information as it available in an index mapping. For instance, let's say you create an index with the following mapping:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then the corresponding index pattern that you will create in Kibana will have the following content:

```
GET .kibana/doc/index-pattern:16a98050-a53f-11e8-82ab-af0d48c6ddd8
{
  "type": "index-pattern",
  "updated_at": "2018-08-21T12:38:22.509Z",
  "index-pattern": {
    "title": "my_index*",
    "timeFieldName": "timestamp",
    "fields": """[{"name":"_id","type":"string","count":0,"scripted":false,"searchable":true,"aggregatable":true,"readFromDocValues":false},{"name":"_index","type":"string","count":0,"scripted":false,"searchable":true,"aggregatable":true,"readFromDocValues":false},{"name":"_score","type":"number","count":0,"scripted":false,"searchable":false,"aggregatable":false,"readFromDocValues":false},{"name":"_source","type":"_source","count":0,"scripted":false,"searchable":false,"aggregatable":false,"readFromDocValues":false},{"name":"_type","type":"string","count":0,"scripted":false,"searchable":true,"aggregatable":true,"readFromDocValues":false},{"name":"name","type":"string","count":0,"scripted":false,"searchable":true,"aggregatable":false,"readFromDocValues":false},{"name":"timestamp","type":"date","count":0,"scripted":false,"searchable":true,"aggregatable":true,"readFromDocValues":true}]"""
  }
}
```

As you can see, Kibana also stores the timestamp field, the name of the index pattern (**which can span several indexes**). Also it stores various properties for each field you have defined, for instance, for the `name` field, the index-pattern contains the following information that Kibana needs to know:

```
  {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string",
    "count": 0,
    "scripted": false,
    "searchable": true,
    "aggregatable": false,
    "readFromDocValues": false
  },
```

Comment: Why does Kibana even needs an index pattern? Can't it just read the index and display it?

Comment: And when I asked if the index pattern affect index creation, I meant if you can somehow use it like a template, since they also correspond with a name pattern?

Comment: See my updated answer. Basically, index template and index pattern are two different beasts, the former allows to create **one index**, while the former can span **several indices**

Comment: We are still not at the bottom of this question --> how does Kibana apply the mappings?  Does it look at the index mappings at all, or does it only consider the index pattern mappings? What are the precedence rules for index mappings versus Kibana index pattern mappings?  When are the mappings applied - at query time, display time? In short, **what is the relationship between the two kinds of mappings?**

Comment: @Banoona the fields available in a Kibana index pattern is a **conjunction** of all the underlying index mappings identified by the index pattern name.